# Show that $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The following question is based on multi-variable calculus and real analysis.

> A set $A\subset [0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$ **iff** every open interval that intersects [0,1] contains a point of A. Suppose $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $f(x)=0,\enspace \forall \enspace x \in A.$ Also assume that $f(x)\geq 0,\enspace \forall \enspace x \in [0,1].\enspace$Show that $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$

I have no idea how to prove the above stuff rigorously. Then only thing I can think of  'if every open interval that intersects $[0,1]$ contains a point of A' is that set A contains all points of the interval $[0,1]$. Being that said it would be obvious for the integral to be zero.
This is all I could think of. I am pretty sure that my assumption would be incorrect.

Comment: $[0, 1] = A  \cup \overline A$ and try to separate the integral into two pars.

Comment: Your intuition about dense sets is wrong, for example in $\mathbb{R}$ the subset $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense (why?) and $\mathbb{Q}\neq\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can try to apply the definition of Riemann sum. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum not sure righht now why you need the positivity

Comment: Show that any lower Riemann sum is $0$. If $f$ is integrable, the integral must then be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following considers the function "Riemann integrable".

Take a Riemann approximation to the integral https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum , i.e. fix $x_0=0<x_1<...<x_n=1$,  and approximate:

$I \sim I_{\text{Riem}}=\sum_i f(x_i^*) (x_{i+1}-x_i)$

where $x_i^*$ belongs to $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$. According to the definition of Riemann integrable functions, $x_i^*$ can be taken any number in the interval and therefore it can be chosen to that $f(x_i^*)=0$ because $A$ is dense.

Therefore $I_{\text{Riem}}=0$. Since we can do this for a partition $P$ whose $\max_i (x_{i+1}-x_i) \rightarrow 0$, this implies that $I=0$. This argument does not use that $f \ge 0$.

If we consider "Lesbegue integrable" functions I think the statement is false since we can have dense sets of zero measure (e.g. the rational numbers). Therefore we can change the value of the function on this set without changing the value of the integral.

I hope not to have forgotten too much about integration theory on $\Bbb{R}$, please let me know if you see any error :)

Comment: You are correct about the Lebesgue integral $-$ the statement is false if we interpret "integrable" to mean "Lebesgue integrable".

Comment: @Thomas        You are right. I am talking about Riemann integration. And thanks a lot for your ans. This problem was eating my brain.

Answer (score 3):

So @Thomas has given a good proof.   But he lies when he says he has forgotten his integration theory.  He remembers it well!

He is also correct when he says the problem is (i) restricted to  Riemann integrable functions and false for the Lebesgue integral, and (ii) the hypothesis that $f(x)\geq 0$ is unnecessary.

In this situation there is always some jerk who butts in to give the *advanced* proof for a question that is clearly posed at the calculus level.

Can't resist!

From a later course in integration you will learn that

1. If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable then it is continuous almost everywhere (i.e., except on a set of measure zero).
2. If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable then it is also Lebesgue integrable and the values agree.
3. If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies  $f(x)=0$  almost everywhere  then
   $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and  $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$.

With these there is an immediate solution to the problem.  Since $f$ is Riemann integrable it is continuous almost everywhere.  Since $f$ is zero on a dense set it must be zero at every point of continuity of $f$.  Hence
$f(x)=0$  almost everywhere,  $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and  $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$ in the sense of the Lebesgue integral and also in the sense of the Riemann integral.

---

---

**P.S.**  Is the Lebesgue integral really that advanced?  Is it too terribly advanced for students to know  that Riemann integrable functions are continuous almost everywhere?

Lebesgue's original presentation of his integral required a good bit of measure theory as a prerequisite.  But that was 1901.  There are now much more elementary ways of introducing that material to early students of real analysis. It is entirely false when someone claims that the Lebesgue integral *requires* measure theory and *needs* one to abandon Riemann sums.  But, alas, most students have to wait many years before they can find a course in integration theory that brings them out of the 19th century.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how can we get around measure theory to construct the Lebesgue-integral?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  Lebesgue tried to find a Riemann sums characterization of his integral, but missed an easy one.   A simple modification of the Riemann definition was found in the 1950s.  You can also define the Lebesgue integral directly from sequences of continuous functions.   And W.H.Young just missed discovering the integral by a couple of years using a method that didn't depend on measure theory.  So you can get around it in multiple ways, some of them easy enough to teach to elementary analysis students.  No concept as important as the Lebesgue integral has only one definition.

Comment: That sounds amazing! Do you happen to have a good reference at hand? One can never know too much about integrals :D

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  Here is a start: https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/ccc/gauge/  and also Peter Lax's Monthly paper:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/40391247.

Comment: That is fantastic! It seems the only real drawback (if we forget about probability theory for a second) is that the function space of gauge-integrable functions is not particularly nice in comparison with the usual $L^1$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  The function space consisting of functions $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ such that both $f$ and $|f|$ are gauge-integrable is exactly the usual $L_1[a,b]$.  McShane in 1969 also gave a variant using Riemann sums that is exactly the same as the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: In the first link you sent the author claims that the space of gauge-integrable functions is strictly larger than $L^1$ (even on a bounded interval). So imposing integrability of the absolute value reduces it to the usual $L^1$? That would be quite convenient, we anyway would want to impose both conditions.

Comment: ( by the way, thanks a lot for taking the time to write this useful post ! Good that you did not resist )

Comment: @B.S.Thomson    Thanks for your post too. It also helped me understand few more stuff :)